# href button doesn't work when set to absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make contact form that slide from the right.
like this page:https://www.fotonaut.cz/en/

It works for me but the button doesn't work when position is set to absolute.
Here is the website: https://test.com/
What I'm doing wrong?
Here is my html code:

```
if ( ! fotografie_blog_header_media_status() ) {
    return;
}
?>
<div class="custom-header">
    <div class="custom-header-media">
        <?php fotografie_blog_header_media(); ?>
        <?php fotografie_blog_header_media_text(); ?>
    </div><!-- .custom-header-media -->
    <div class="custom-header-overlay"></div><!-- .custom-header-overlay -->
</div><!-- .custom-header -->

<!-- cd-panel -->
        <a href="#0" class="cd-btn js-cd-panel-trigger" data-panel="main"><span>Enquiry</span></a>
    <div class="cd-panel cd-panel--from-right js-cd-panel-main">
        <div class="cd-panel__container">
            <div class="cd-panel__content">
<?php $contact='[contact-form-7 id="1265" title="Contact slider"]'?>
<?php echo do_shortcode($contact);?>
<p class="contactside">It’s easy. Tell us about your event in detail and we'll get back to you with all the necessary information about Fotonaut including pricing.</p>
    </div> 
</div>
```

and here is my css code for the button:

```
.cd-btn.js-cd-panel-trigger {
    background-color: unset;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 5rem;
    border-radius: 1em;
    width: 5rem;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-40%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-40%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateX(-40%) translateY(-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: there may be another element on the form that has a `z-index` specified and it's being place on top of the anchor, you can try setting a `z-index` on the anchor to see if that's the case

Comment: oh ıt works :D put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may be another element on the form that has a `z-index` specified and it's being place on top of the anchor, you can try setting a z-index on the anchor to see if that's the case

```
.cd-btn.js-cd-panel-trigger{
    z-index: 100;
    /*...*/
}
```